# How to upload image file in jmeter with <timeinmillsec>+imagefilename

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

some folder path contains list of images as follows :

```
m405set1.jpg
m405set2.jpg
m405set3.jpg
m405set4.jpg
m405set5.jpg
```

My requirement is i want to readfirst filename upload image file in following format :

```
<gettimeinmilliseconds>+imagename.jpg example 1451989954976m405set1.jpg
```

How i can achive this please help me on this

Comment: You want to do a post to a certain url and use a different file for each iteration ? The files are stored in a flat directory and you could write a list of them in a csv file ? What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to add current timestamp to the file name you can use [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function as a prefix to the file parameter. Without arguments the function returns current time in milliseconds since [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

---

If you need to change file name before uploading it is more tricky but still possible.

1. Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which does the upload
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   String newFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + vars.get("oldFileName");
   FileUtils.copyFile(new File("test.txt"),new File(newFileName));
   vars.put("newFileName",newFileName);
   ```

   it will append current timestamp to file specified in `${oldFileName}` variable (it may originate from i.e. [CSV Data Set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and store the resulting value into `${newFileName}` variable which you can use in the actual upload request
3. Optionally you can add a step to clean up generated temporary file in case if you don't need it after the request. To do so add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) with the following code:

   ```
   String filename = vars.get("newFileName");
   new File(filename).delete();
   ```

Clarifications:

- [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) is a class from Apache Commons IO library which simplifies file operations
- `vars` - is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) instance, it provides read/write access to all JMeter Variables

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for comprehensive information on using Beanshell scripting in your JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks For Detailed Explanation Dmitri T.

Comment: with following methods i achieved what i want FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory tfile1.renameTo(tPattern);new Date().getTime()